# MySQL query word link

Tags: mysql

I want to link two word in statement in query like:

```
LEFT JOIN table as tt on tt.object=’SOMEWORD#’key1.key
```

How i can do this? We want to find SOMEWORD#23 , offcorse where we got key1.key we got key 23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Concat()` function of Mysql (as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)). Your query will be:

`LEFT JOIN table as tt on tt.object=CONCAT('SOMEWORD#', key1.key);`

Comment: Thanks for help! I don’t know where i can find this.

Comment: @DominikTraskowski You can find it in the list of string functions in the MySQL documentation. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html